I cannnot use internet and file access at the same time on ethernet crossover
I have 2 pcs connected via ethernet crossover. main pc is connected to internet via wifi. but i cannot share files and use the internet at the same time on the second pc (it does not support wifi). i want to use the internet and local ethernet at the same time. (im guessing a way to not use dhcp). please tell me what to do

What IP configuration do you have on both interfaces? (ifconfig output is fine) Specifically, do both of them have a 'default gateway' or just one?

The way you worded your post implies that the "second pc" is only able to either  "share files" or "use the internet" at any given time. What is the first PC capable of? Is it limited also? What determines each mode? How do you configure the system to enable either capability/mode?

First you need to say which OSes the first PC is running (Windows, MacOS, Linux, and which version, e.g. Win7, Win10, Win11)?

The easiest solution will be to get a USB-WiFi-Adapter, they are really inexpensive if you buy a used one ($5-15) on your fav internet marketplace.
